# How does filter affect LEFT JOIN in sql

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I'm trying to understand why the following query only returns one row in spite of `LEFT JOIN`

```sql
with t1(day_partition, entity_id, feature_1) AS (values
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_1', 'x'),
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_2', 'y')
),

t2(day_partition, entity_id, feature_2) AS (values
  ('2020-05-15', 'id_1', 1)
)

SELECT
  t1.day_partition AS day_partition_1,
  t2.day_partition AS day_partition_2,
  t1.entity_id AS entity_id_1,
  t2.entity_id AS entity_id_2
FROM
  t1
LEFT JOIN
  t2
ON
  t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id
WHERE
  t2.day_partition = '2020-05-15'
;
```

returns

```
 day_partition_1 | day_partition_2 | entity_id_1 | entity_id_2 
-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------
 2020-05-15      | 2020-05-15      | o1          | o1
```

However, removing the filter of

```
WHERE
  t2.day_partition = '2020-05-15'
```

will return

```
 day_partition_1 | day_partition_2 | entity_id_1 | entity_id_2 
-----------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------
 2020-05-15      | 2020-05-15      | id_1        | id_1        
 2020-05-15      | NULL            | id_2        | NULL
```

I find such behavior unintuitive and what's the rule behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. Conditions in the `where` clause are mandatory so putting there a condition on the `left join`ed table ends up evicting rows where the `left join` came back empty. Basically, this turns the `left join` to an `inner join`.

You need to put all predicates that relate to columns coming from the `left join`ed table in the `on` clause of the join:

```
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id
    AND t2.day_partition = '2020-05-15'
```

By looking at your resultset, I tend to think that you actually wanted a condition on `t1`:

```
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id
WHERE t1.day_partition = '2020-05-15'
```

Comment: by "left joined table", do you mean the table on the right, i.e. `t2` in my example?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the condition in the `join` it works as you expect

```
SELECT
  t1.day_partition AS day_partition_1,
  t2.day_partition AS day_partition_2,
  t1.entity_id AS entity_id_1,
  t2.entity_id AS entity_id_2
FROM
  t1
LEFT JOIN
  t2
ON
  t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id AND t2.day_partition = '2020-05-15'
```

The query parser does not know what you are thinking. If you filter the data in a  `where` clause it affects all records and not just the records of the joined table.

Comment: could you please clarify more what do you mean by "The query parser does not know what you are thinking"?

Comment: You asked what kind of sense your query makes. You want to filter only records of the joined table. But the database engine does not know your intentions. It just fitlers all you add in the `where` clause